# Ширина аналога сетки bootstrap под разные разрешения

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Хотел разобратся как работает сетка бутстрапа на своем примере, но никак не могу придумать как менять аквивный класс для определенного разрешения. Вот пример для одного разрешения. Как стоило бы применять тот же `^col-xs-`  для другого разрешения

```css
.row:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: ''; }

.row + .row {
  margin-top: 3%; }

[class^="col-"] {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 3%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
  [class^="col-"]:last-child {
    margin-right: 0%; }

.col-md-1 {
  width: 5.58333%; }

.col-md-2 {
  width: 14.16667%; }

.col-md-3 {
  width: 22.75%; }

.col-md-4 {
  width: 31.33333%; }

.col-md-5 {
  width: 39.91667%; }

.col-md-6 {
  width: 48.5%; }

.col-md-7 {
  width: 57.08333%; }

.col-md-8 {
  width: 65.66667%; }

.col-md-9 {
  width: 74.25%; }

.col-md-10 {
  width: 82.83333%; }

.col-md-11 {
  width: 91.41667%; }

.col-md-12 {
  width: 100%; }

.col-xs-1 {
  width: 5.58333%; }

.col-xs-2 {
  width: 14.16667%; }

.col-xs-3 {
  width: 22.75%; }

.col-xs-4 {
  width: 31.33333%; }

.col-xs-5 {
  width: 39.91667%; }

.col-xs-6 {
  width: 48.5%; }

.col-xs-7 {
  width: 57.08333%; }

.col-xs-8 {
  width: 65.66667%; }

.col-xs-9 {
  width: 74.25%; }

.col-xs-10 {
  width: 82.83333%; }

.col-xs-11 {
  width: 91.41667%; }

.col-xs-12 {
  width: 100%; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                 col-6
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                col-6
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                col-6
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неверно поняли концепцию сетки Bootstrap. Вам ненужно самому переопределять стили `col-xs`, вам нужно `div` дополнить классами, которые бы отвечали за отображение на других разрешениях дисплея - `.col-sm, .col-md, .col-lg`. Именно эти классы и будут переопределять стандартные стили `col-xs`.

Суть работы сетки в том, чтобы в сумме все цифры в классах на блоках, которые должны быть на одной строке, равнялись 12.

То есть, 6+6=12, поэтому два блока на одной строке. А если вы хотите 4 блока разместить на одной строке, тогда замените на `.col-lg-3` (3+3+3+3=12).

На практике это выглядит так:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">2</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">3</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">4</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Если же в целом вам Bootstrap нужен только для сетки и вы сами хотите контролировать разрешение, при котором вы хотите менять верстку и при этом не использовать кучу классов, я бы рекомендовал использовать подобную сетку (написана на Stylus):

```
.col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12
    position relative
    min-height 1px
    padding 0 15px
    @media (min-width 720px)
        display inline-block
        vertical-align top

@media (min-width 720px)
    .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12
        width 100%
    .col-5
        width 83.33333333%
    .col-4
        width 66.66666667%
    .col-3
        width 50%
    .col-2
        width 33.33333333%
    .col-1
        width 16.66666667%

@media (min-width 1024px)
    .col-12
        width 100%
    .col-11
        width 91.66666667%
    .col-10
        width 83.33333333%
    .col-9
        width 75%
    .col-8
        width 66.66666667%
    .col-7
        width 58.33333333%
    .col-6
        width 50%
    .col-5
        width 41.66666667%
    .col-4
        width 33.33333333%
    .col-3
        width 25%
    .col-2
        width 16.66666667%
    .col-1
        width 8.33333333%
```

Comment: но ели допустим в одном разрешении 33.3! % ширина блока, а в другом должно быть 25% то разве это дополнение?

Comment: @ddeadlink да. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: суть теперь более понятна, но как коррелировать ширину если разные разрешения. На ум приходит только куча медиа запросов

Comment: @ddeadlink так использование бутстрап и нужно вам для того, чтобы не писать кучу медиа запросов - за вас уже они написаны в библиотеки. Рекомендую вам открыть исходных код бутстрап и посмотреть самому, как в нем реализована сетка.

Comment: это и хотел уточнить) спасибо за ответы